# What is a fence-hang / handling fence / blown-fence error?

Tags: ios

I had an iOS iPad app crash and got the following crash log from the Devices tab:

```
Date/Time:       2017-10-13 15:06:22 -0600
OS Version:      iPhone OS 11.1 (Build 15B5066f)
Architecture:    arm64
Report Version:  26

Data Source:     KPerf Lightweight PET
Kernel Cache:    0xffffffe000000000 1C4A9D92-74B9-1F20-096E-27915D7A6C03
Reason:          Fence-hang-Vocab: 505ms handling fence, blown-fence (fence duration=505ms)

Command:         Vocab
Path:            /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9F4A7C15-D23E-46C8-B724-84C57D83B455/Vocab.app/Vocab
Identifier:      com.mycompany.Vocab
Version:         1.4.0 (420)
Parent:          debugserver [1467]
PID:             1469

Duration:        0.55s
Steps:           11 (50ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  J71AP
Active cpus:     2
```

Any insight into what this error is and what causes it?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Apple Developer Forums Thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86853), one cause of blown fence errors is due to high memory pressure.

The developer of the app in question might be able to monitor memory pressure of the app, which could be a cause for the app being terminated.